# Какие есть инструменты для поиска утечек памяти?

Tags: linux, утечка-памяти

До недавнего времени пользовался `valgrind` пока не наткнулся на баг, связанный с [`amd64`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html). В результате из-за этого бага не могу тестировать программы на `qt`. Подскажите какие еще есть хорошие инструменты для поиска утечек памяти для `linux` и, желательно, консольные. Спс.

Comment: Есть такой ресурс сам редко захожу, но наверное нужно почаще) может вы для себя что-то найдете - [Linux Perf](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html)

Answer (score 0):

Мелкие баги прои отладке кьютовых прог помогпет ловть `/dev/brain`.

Если они возникают систематически, то вероятен баг в фреймворке или неправильное испльзование оного. В первом случае стоит отписаться в багзилллу, перед этим трижды проверев, что вероятен именно фреймворк.